# JavaScript Class Inheritance Strange Behaviour on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, inheritance, backbone.js

I am working with a Backbone app, and have some views inheriting from my other custom views. In order to inherit events defined by the parent view I have used `_.extend({}, superEvents, this.events)` in the child's constructor. This works fine everywhere except in Firefox. In Firefox (tested on 21) extended events include only super events, no events defined with `this.events`.

Below is the code. Also made a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6wFeY/3/)

```
var ParentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click .nav-icon.cancel': 'hideView'
    },

    initialize: function() { },

    hideView: function (event) { }
});


var ChildView = ParentView.extend({
    events: {
        'click .items a': 'doSomething'
    },

    constructor: function () {
        // Save reference of the super class prototype
        this.super = ParentView.prototype;

        //console.log(this.events);        // uncomment it and it will work fine
        this.events = $.extend({}, this.super.events, this.events);
        console.log(this.events);

        this.super.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.super.initialize.call(this);    
    },

    doSomething: function (event) { }

});
```

**Note:** When I made events in child a local variable or change it's name to something else e.g `childEvents` it works fine. Surprisingly if I do a `console.log(this.events)` before extending it works fine.

Comment: works for me on Linux/Firefox 17.0.6: 
Object { click .nav-icon.cancel="hideView", click .items a="doSomething"}

Comment: Looks like the problem is with just Firefox 21